# ARGV in Processing

Tags: python, processing

I have an application written in Processing using Python Mode and I didn't find in any place in the Processing documentation about using `argv` arguments. I need that the a variable value be passed as a parameter to determine my application behaviour. To let the things clearly, I'm doing a RPM simulator that has a little circle with a translation move around a big circle. My current source is:

```
rpm = 27

def setup():
    size(600, 600)
    rectMode(CENTER)
    ellipseMode(RADIUS)
    noFill()
    stroke(33, 33, 33)
    smooth()

def draw():
    background(2, 135, 208)
    fill(100, 100, 100)
    ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, 280, 280)
    translate(width / 2, height / 2)
    angle = frameCount * parameter_table(rpm)
    x = cos(angle) * 280
    y = sin(angle) * 280
    fill(23, 187, 176)
    stroke(10)
    smooth()
    ellipse(x, y, 20, 20)


def parameter_table(rpm):
    return 10.0 * 0.01 / (60.0 / rpm)
```

How can I dynamically set the RPM via command line, calling `/home/my_application 27`?

Comment: Have you tried the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module?

Comment: Maybe [google can help...](https://www.google.com.br/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=comand+line+args+site:processing.org&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=UK1iVNTwEuuB8Qe9_YDYCw#rls=en&q=command+line+args+site:processing.org&spell=1)

Comment: I already had visited all the links in the page you sent me. I solved it by, in Java, creating a main method `public static void main(String args[])` that, after get the arguments, starts the setup and loops the draw: `PApplet.main(new String[] { "simulator" });`